# Is there a surface S$\subset R^3$ whose Gaussian curvature is -1 at each point S?

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, surfaces, curvature

Is there a surface $S\subset \Bbb R^3$ whose Gaussian curvature is $-1$ at each point $S$?

At first I think this does not make a sense.

But googling and googling.. I found a 'final exam problem'

https://www.ma.utexas.edu/users/dafr/M365G/Final_soln.pdf

question no.$7$ says my question is TRUE..

How can I think the surface whose Gaussian curvature is $-1$ every point.

And is there a surface whose Gaussian curvature is constant $K<0$??

Thanks for reading my question.

Comment: [Pseudosphere](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudosphere)

Comment: I suspect any embedding of a pseudosphere/surface of constant negative curvature in $\mathbb{R}^3$ will have a singularity, as the tractricoid does (see illustration in article linked by Daniel above).

Comment: Wow. Thanks a lot. Now I'm gonna study about Pseudosphere. Really thank you.

Comment: @hardmath: You might be thinking about Hilbert's Theorem. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert's_theorem_(differential_geometry) Notice, though, that it has a hypothesis of completeness. The interior of the pseudosphere is itself an example of an embedded surface of constant negative curvature in $\mathbb{R}^3$, but it lacks completeness.

Comment: @Lee Mosher Thanks a lot. Hilbert's Thm..